# Angularjs form validation fails on directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I have a form on a page which is validated just fine if all the form elements are on the page, http://jsfiddle.net/nkanand4/6za8h8xg/1/.

```
<div ng-form="myform">
  <div>
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required name="input"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This, however, stops working if I am doing a wizard kind of form, where each step is populated using directive, http://jsfiddle.net/nkanand4/pe17afvq/2/.

```
<div ng-form="myform">
  <form-element step="selectedStep"></form-element>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this will be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**: 
I initially had started with ng-include but dropped that approach because if I use it, the data is not persisted from step 1 to step 2 to back to step 1. Reason being a new scope is created when you move back and forth. Hence I needed a way to keep all the data under a scope property, like $scope.data.user.name, so that i can pass back $scope.data when its requested.

Answer (score 2):

Don't compile HTML yourself, you can let Angular do it properly for you:

```
.directive('formElement', function($log, $templateCache, $compile) {
    return {
        template: '<div ng-include="\'step\' + selectedStep.step + \'.html\'">',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // ... nothing really here
        }
    };
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pe17afvq/4/

Comment: I updated my question with my reasons of why I did not want to use ng-include in the first place. Please suggest anything if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it sorted out. This was reported as a bug on angularJS issue tracker, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7519. The trick is to use the clone in the link function that is returned when you are using $compile.

```
$compile(html)(scope, function(clone) {
   elem.empty().append(clone);
});
```

Updated my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkanand4/pe17afvq/5/) accordingly, and it works!